# how to find the shortest distance in geomatry route?

Tags: math, geometry

[image]

here black dots draws a line, it may have n dots, my problem is to find the shortest distance between the green dot and the line (not black dots)

Comment: Do you only want lines between black dots that are in order, or do you want all possible lines between black dots?  In other words, wouldn't the green dot closest to the line between (4,7.7) and (4.1,17)? Or maybe (4,7.7) and the (unnumbered) black dot after (4.1,17)?  Also, do you want to extend the **lines** past the dots, or only the **line segement** between dots?

Comment: I need only the shortest distance between the dot and line segment

Answer (score 2):

the distance between line and point is already answered in:
[Shortest distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)

you just need add another part to loop all the line segments and find the shortest one.

Comment: using a hierarchical data structure in the case of large graphs can help as well :)